# Firestore listener not working on App Engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs

I have a NestJS app deployed to App Engine (Standard), the app uses the Firebase-Admin SDK to listen for real time updates to documents (Firestore). The app works fine locally, whenever a document changes, the listener runs as expected. However, when the app is deployed to App Engine, document changes aren't causing the listener to run. My App Engine instance and Firebase project both are in the same GCP project, and the default App Engine service account has Firebase Admin privileges. I'm kinda stuck, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine Standard env doesn't support web sockets, switching to Flex env fixed my issue.